# how to include all project gems into the gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I work as a developer supporting several apps built in Rails, often I need to install gems that are not included into the gem file.

Last day I build a project and when I try to run it on another computer I experienced some issues with missing gems, a lot actually and I didn't know where to get a list of all the missing gems or how to install them.

The question is, is there a way to include all the gems that the project needs into the gem file so next time someone try to run it on another computer it will be enough to use the comand `bundle install`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not adding these gems to the Gemfile?

Comment: yes, I only add the gems that I specifically install (ex. paperclip), but for example if my project uses active-record 3.2.6 among others I don't add them one by one to my gem file, some times I'm not even aware of all the gems that my project require, and the most important the projects that I work with doesn't have them either.
Maybe I'm doing it wrong, if someone could guide me I'll appreciated.

Comment: Active Record is a rails dependency, so by having `gem 'rails', '3.2.6'` in your Gemfile will automatically install it's dependencies. When switching to a new computer you would need to run `bundle install` to install all of those missing gems.

Comment: ok, so the answer will be, Include the main gems like rails 3.2.6 and it will install all dependencies when using bundle install and include all the 'additional' gems that I use in the gem file ?

Comment: ^^ Regarding your comment about not being aware of all the gems a project uses - you can try looking at the `Gemfile.lock` file, which is a compilation of the gem dependencies that `bundle install` calculates - this is a list essentially of all the gems being used and their dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the Gems in your Gemfile, and then run `bundle install` on ANY new machine in order to install those Gems and their dependencies. For example:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
```

With this example, all dependencies of rails such as Active Record, Action Pack and so on will be installed when bundler installs rails. The same for the remaining gems and their dependencies.

If you are planning, and it appears that you are, to spend much time with rails, you should really read up on [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/).

Comment: I can however say, from experience (using `rails 3.1.3`) that Bundler does not always work as expected - I have found that the first time you ever run it on a machine, it generally downloads all gems and their dependencies - however after that it seems finicky, and I've had multiple issues with `bundle install` not getting all the needed gems. Sometimes you may also need to delete the `Gemfile.lock` file (bundler will re-create this) - or try running `bundle update` to force gems to be updated. I agree with @janders223 - understanding how the gems are packaged is really helpful :)

Comment: While I don't disagree that Bundler can be picky, I cannot agree with deleting the .lock file. Gemfile.lock is what 'locks' in the specific versions  of the gems you are running at that time. As Gems are open source they are updated often, and often introduce non-backwards compatible breaking changes that are hard to diagnose. running `bundle update <gemname>` for a specific gem is a far better solution than a full update as you don't know what will play nice together and what won't.

Comment: Hmm I certainly agree with you there, a lot of gems do change often and can be non-backwards compatible - I suppose I have found removing the `.lock` file a good solution since we specify the versions of gems we use, and removing the lock file forces bundler to re-analyze things. However, I completely agree with you that it could backfire if you are not specifying specific gem versions.